# Loop over multiple values in Jinja

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, jinja2

I have a dict of lists which look like this:

```py
context = {"x":["col1", "col2", "col3"], "a":["val1","val2","val3"], "b":["val4","val5","val6"]}
```

** I have particular reasons for this structure. (read bellow)

I'm passing this data from `views.py` to `file.html` like

`return render(request, "main/file.html", context)`

And I'm looping like this to get a data to table in html to look like a `csv file` (horizontaly)

```html
<table id = "table_one", style="font-size:12px;">
    <tr>
      {% if x %}    # Creating column names
        {% for y in x %}
        <th>{{ y }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>{{ a.0 }}</td> # First data(first row) for the first column name
        <td>{{ b.0 }}</td> # First data(first row) for the second column name etc....
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ a.1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ b.1 }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ a.2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ b.2 }}</td>   
      </tr>
```

It makes something like this:

```
col1    col2   col3
val1    val2   val3
val4    val5   val6
```

Which works (`col1` contains `val1` and `val4` which have a relationship). But I have to make a lot of  tags, when I want to render more than two rows of values. I would like to make this for all data in `a` and `b`, which are thousands of rows....
Why I'm creating `a` and `b` in my `views.py` for the dictionary and not sending data to html in form `{'col1':'val1','val4', 'col2':...`?
Because the names of columns are different for each requests, so I need something that doesn't change over the time. 
How Could I rewrite it to make it usable for the whole length of the data?

Answer (score 0):

combine the content of `a` & `b` and then iterate in template.

**Ex:**

```
#in View
context = {"x":["col1", "col2", "col3"], "data":[["val1","val2","val3"]] + [["val4","val5","val6"]]}
```

In Template:

```
<table id = "table_one", style="font-size:12px;">
    <tr>
      {% if x %}    # Creating column names
        {% for y in x %}
        <th>{{ y }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% for m, n, o in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ m }}</td> 
        <td>{{ n }}</td>
        <td>{{ o }}</td>etc....
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understoond well, but you may pass data as a list of lists:

```
context = {"x":["col1", "col2", "col3"], "data":[["val1","val2","val3"], ["val4","val5","val6"]]}
```

and print them with a double for:

```
{% for row in data %}
      <tr>
          {% for col in row %}
              <td>{{ col }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Do you please tell me hint how could I merge "a", "b" cols to one "data" with that list of lists inside please?

Comment: In views.py, I suppose in a similar way you've constructed `"a":["val1","val2","val3"]` or `"b":["val4","val5","val6"]`